# Database time data retrieval, time based queries

Tags: php, mysql, database, time

I am new to time manipulation or time arithmetic operations
and am currently developing a navigation system with Web server based information and currently I have this Database that contains a table peek hours whose columns are id, start_time, end_time , edge_id, day_of_the_week, edge_weight

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  Peek Hours                                           |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    |            |           |         |                 |             |
| id | start_time |  end_time | edge_id | day_of_the_week | edge_weight |
|    |            |           |         |                 |             |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using PHP as a webservice and so based on the current time i want to get all the records that would fit this equation

`start_time< current_time < end_time`

Comment: Do you have problem with the SQL? In any case you'll need one `SELECT` statement with a `WHERE` and an `AND` clauses ;-) And you'll have to watch the formats of `current_time`, which I suppose you get from your script, and of `start_time`, respectively `end_time`. Both PHP and MySQL have functionality inbuilt to format date, time and datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other comments suggest, you didn't look very hard.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM peek_hours
 WHERE start_time < NOW()
 AND NOW() < end_time
```

You can also do this:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM peek_hours
 WHERE NOW() between start_time AND end_time
```

Although BETWEEN is "less than or equal to".